# can`t get data from JSON array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Using jQuery and PHP I got json array, but somehow I can't manage to get data out of it. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "php/global_functions.php",
data: {callFunction: "getNewsTitles"},
cache: false,
success: function(result){
    alert(result);
    //[{"heading":"Ritens pie sienas tiek nozagts","text":"Zilu 2008.gada BMW m\u0113s at\u013cauties tom\u0113r nevaram"},{"heading":"Dzied\u0101t\u0101ja Aliwka par CityTaxi","text":"Teksts 123 Teksts"},{"heading":"Kvalit\u0101tes uzlabo\u0161ana P\u0101rdaugav\u0101","text":"Fant\u0101zija nozaga kaimi\u0146a ka\u0137i"},{"heading":"CityTaxi papla\u0161ina autoparku","text":"Fant\u0101zija sit augstu vilni"},{"heading":"CityTaxi iekaro R\u012bgu","text":"Te iet kaut k\u0101ds teksts, piem\u0113ram - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pellentesque nisl id lobortis congue. Ut commodo tortor eget dapibus gravida. Sed accumsan orci ac ante dignissim feugiat."}]
    alert(result[1].heading);
    //undefined
}
});
```

I commented results which appears on alerts. Why does it give me `undefined`?

Comment: try parsing the string into json first:
    var json = JSON.parse(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the result using:

```
var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
```

You can also set the datatype to be JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "php/global_functions.php",
    data: {callFunction: "getNewsTitles"},
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
        alert(result[1].heading);
    }
});
```

Or use the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) jQuery method.